# checkbox запоминает при возврате на страницу

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Имеется данный код суть такая что нельзя выбирать больше 5 чекбоксов(у меня их 10). Все работает но проблема в том что когда человек возвращаться назад после сабмита, checkbox остаются выбраными, а наш масив успешно чиститься и человек может выбирать еще. Подскажите решение.

```
(function() {
    var checklist = [];

    document.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
        var el = evt.target;
        if (checklist.length > 4) {
            el.checked = false;
        }

        console.log(checklist);
        if (el.checked && checklist.length < 5) {
            checklist.push(el);

        } else {
            var idx = checklist.indexOf(el);
            if (idx > -1) {
                checklist.splice(idx, 1);
            }

        }

        document.getElementById("klv_podarkov").innerHTML = 5 - checklist.length;
        if (checklist.length > 4) {
            document.getElementById("buttonsubmit").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("buttonsubmit").disabled = true;
        }
    }, false);
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно количество отмеченных checkbox вычислять на лету.

Получаем все чекбоксы, и считаем количество checked.

```js
var allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
var arrayAllCheckboxes = Array.from(allCheckboxes);
arrayAllCheckboxes.forEach(x => x.addEventListener("change",Changed));

function Changed() {
   // расчитываем количество отмеченных checkbox
   var checkedCheckboxes = arrayAllCheckboxes.filter(x=>x.checked);
   var count = checkedCheckboxes.length;
   console.log(count);
}

Changed();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="n1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="n2" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="n3" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="n4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="n5" />
```

Или можно даже сразу в одну строчку рассчитать количество отмеченных checkbox - `document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length`.

```js
var allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
    var arrayAllCheckboxes = Array.from(allCheckboxes);
    arrayAllCheckboxes.forEach(x => x.addEventListener("change",Changed));

    function Changed() {
       // расчитываем количество отмеченных checkbox
       var count = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
       console.log(count);
    }

    Changed();
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" name="n1" checked />
    <input type="checkbox" name="n2" checked />
    <input type="checkbox" name="n3" checked />
    <input type="checkbox" name="n4" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="n5" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @DimaZavada пожалуйста, если ответ помог можете так же его залайкать.